# 'Error' message: 'Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body. (arrow-body-style)'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm using "eslint-config-airbnb": "13.0.0", to keep my JavaScript clean

```
export const netralize = repatchThunk(() => (dispatch, getState, repatch) => {
  dispatch({ type: `${DOMAIN}/NETRALIZE` })
  repatch((state) => {
    return state.merge(fromJS)({
      userList: [],
      userListPagination: {},
    })
  })
})
```

I receive the warning

```
Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body. (arrow-body-style)'
```

Comment: The issue is with this `() => (dispatch, getState, repatch) =>`.Do like this `repatchThunk((dispatch, getState, repatch) => { //rest of the code`

Comment: Whenever you get an eslint message, take the actual error definition (in this case `arrow-body-style`) and paste it into Google. The official rule documentation will tell you what is wrong, why you shouldn't do it, and how to disable it if you disagree.